# What type in the typing module describes a class? What type describes a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-3.5, python-typing

The new `typing` module in Python 3.5 provides a number of tools for use in type annotations. Does it provide an object or type that encapsulates the idea of *class*? How about the idea of *function*?

In the following code, which defines a decorator, what should stand in for `class_`? What should stand in for `function`? (`typing.Callable` is inadequate, because for example a class is callable, but the code is trying to identify methods.) (The `no_type_check()` decorator in the `typing` module itself might be a prototype for decorators that act like this. `no_type_check()` itself does not have any annotations, type-hint or otherwise.)

```
import typing

def is_double_underscore_name (name):
    return len(name) > 4 and name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__')

# This code will not run, because 'class_' and 'function' are names that do not have any
# predefined meaning. See the text of the question.

# Note: This modifies classes in-place but (probably) does not modify functions in-place;
# this is not a considered design decision; it is just the easiest thing to do in a very
# basic example like this.
def do_something (class_or_function: typing.Union[class_, function]):
    if isinstance(class_or_function, class_):
        for name in class_or_function.__dict__:
            if not is_double_underscore_name(name):
                object = class_or_function.__dict__[name]
                if isinstance(object, function):
                    class_or_function.__dict__[name] = do_something(object)
        return class_or_function
    else:
        ... # return the function, modified in some way
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are instances of the type `type`.

Functions are of the types `types.FunctionType` or `types.BuiltinFunctionType`.

Methods are of the types `types.MethodType` or `types.BuiltinMethodType`.

`types` has been a part of Python for... a very long time.

Comment: Yup, it's not new.  And it was gutted in 3.5.  "Purity beats practicality" is the motto of 3.x

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard `types` was [not gutted in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/types.html). No idea where you got that from.

Comment: From comparing types in 2.7 to 3.5?  Wish all questions were that easy to answer.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard: `types` was cleaned up in 3.0, mostly removing a large number of obsolete names. For example, `types.IntType` has been obsolete since `int` was changed from a factory function to a name for the actual int type. Other removed names correspond to types that don't exist any more. The only removed name I remember that doesn't fit this pattern is `types.NoneType`, but you can just use `type(None)` for that.