# type hint for class type as argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing, ros2

In the python client library of ros2 there is a function that accepts the class type as an argument (not an instance of that class, but the definition).

For example

```
from std_msgs.msg import String
#String is python class i.e,
#class String:
#    ...

class MyNode(Node)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('my_node')
        self.add_subscription(String, 'chatter', lambda msg : print(msg))
        #Note that we pass in the type String, not an object, i.e String()
```

How could something like this be annotated using the python type annotations?

One way would be to use the `Executable` type hint, as the class type can be called with `()` to construct an object. But this doesn't convey it's true meaning very well.

```
def foo(class_type: Executable):
   obj: Any = class_type()
```

It would be better if there was something like:

```
def foo(class_type: Class):
   object: Any = class_type()
```

Is there anything like this? What is the standard way to do this?

Ideally I would like this to work with the MyPy static type check system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hints with user defined classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664040/type-hints-with-user-defined-classes)

Comment: @Georgy Not directly. That is asking how to use a custom class, to anotate that the function takes an instance of that class. I want it to take a class itself. It can be any class, as long as it is a class definition, and not an object. But that answer has given me the idea to use `Type[Any]`. That could work.

Comment: Oh, ok. It wasn't immediately clear for me that you are looking for a type hint for *any* class. Linking related questions (not sure if they are appropriate duplicate targets, though): [Python type hint for (any) class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44325153/7851470), [What type in the typing module describes a class? What type describes a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34458848/7851470).

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a type hint for what you want, it is just called [`Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) instead of `Class`.

As you can also see, you can tell it what it should be a class of, so in the example you gave it would be:

```py
Type[String]
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all, i.e. calling `@classmethod` will fail with `has no attribute`